# Python script hangs when trying to connect to SQL databse

Tags: python, database, postgresql

Python script hangs when I run it. Not sure what is getting it stuck. Just had a battle with having to install new ODBC Drivers for postgres, could that be the reason?

```py
import pyodbc 

server = 'localhost'
database = 'screens_database'
username = 'postgres'
password = ''
driver='{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}'

cxcn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER='+driver+';SERVER='+server+';PORT=5000;DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+password)


#cursor
cur = con.cursor()

cur.execute("select * from screens_database")

con.close()
```

Comment: Put debug statements in your code, to check after which line your code gets stuck

Comment: It gets stick on line 8 where we try to establish the connection.

Comment: Print the string that is the argument to `connect`. Does it look like what you expect?

Comment: @exor523 try connecting manually to the DB with an SQL client

Comment: You want to use the ODBC Driver 17 for *SQL Server* to connect to a *PostgreSQL* database? That sounds ... wrong. Besides, is there any restriction in your environment that keeps you from using the [`psycopg2`](http://initd.org/psycopg/) driver?